# Flutter - How to determine using Firestore when network unconnected

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore in an App that I'm working on. When connected to the Internet it works fine. When not connected to the internet I want to know that it's not connected and or be able to control the timeout. When attempting to upload an image with the internet unconnected, I receive a response after 718 seconds.
How can I test via Flutter/Firestore whether the internet is connected and how can I prevent such a long timeout?
Please note: the code works fine when online.
Relevant code is below:

```
    _stopwatch.start();
    print("Waiting for storage ref");
    final StorageReference storageRef =
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(
'$sFilename.jpg');
    print("Putting file");
    final StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
storageRef.putFile(imageFile);
    print("waiting for snapshot");
    final StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = (await
uploadTask.onComplete);
    print("Waiting for download url");
    var vImageUrl = (await
snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
} catch (vError) {
      _stopwatch.stop;
      _sLastError =
      "${getDateTime()} uploadImage: Elapsed:
${_stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds ~/ 1000} seconds,
Size = $iSize,  Error = ${vError.toString()}";
    _logError(_sLastError);
    throw (_sLastError);
 }
```

```
The response on screen is as follows:
Waiting for storage ref
I/flutter (15999): Putting file
I/flutter (15999): waiting for snapshot
I/flutter (15999): EVENT StorageTaskEventType.progress
I/flutter (15999): EVENT StorageTaskEventType.progress
I/flutter (15999): EVENT StorageTaskEventType.failure
I/flutter (15999): Waiting for download url
I/flutter (15999): Image upload failed
I/flutter (15999): FirestoreService: 163 2019-05-11
  00:28 uploadImage: Elapsed: 718 seconds, Size =
  49302,  Error = PlatformException(download_error,
 The operation retry limit has been exceeded., null)
```

Comment: There is a plugin to check network connectivity, have a look in this: https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity

Comment: @Moujabr. Thanks, I was going to look at that, but I think I have solved it with Firestore - as per my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Firestore does not currently have a solution to this. The way that I have appeared to have solved it for myself in the short-term is to, within a transaction, attempt to get a document. If that results with an error, then there is not an internet connection. This appears to work. Prior to loading an image, I (within a transaction) attempt to load an document(await tx.get(docRef)). If that fails with an error, then there is not an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

The below mentioned piece of code might help you. I'm using this code to detect whether internet is available or not. This is very helpful in cases where WiFi is connected but internet is unavailable.

```
try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        print('connected');
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      print('not connected');
     //Here you can setState a bool like internetAvailable = false;
     //or use call this before uploading data to firestore/storage depending upon the result, you can move on further.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did encounter that in my search for a solution. The one that I have chosen uses Firestore and is instantaneous (10ms). I wanted to use Firestore if possible.